# Updating Tickets count from the Bookings model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a ticket booking app for my sample project using Ruby on Rails 4.1. Three are three models - Events, Tickets and Bookings. Events have many tickets and bookings. Tickets have many bookings and they belong to events. Bookings belongs to events and tickets.

Here's the ticket model:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :bookings

 def maximum_tickets_allowed
   (1..maximum_quantity.to_i).to_a
 end
end
```

One of the model methods in Booking.rb is:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :ticket
  has_many :charges

def check_ticket_count
  count = ticket.ticket_quantity.to_i - order_quantity.to_i
  ticket.ticket_quantity = count
end
```

This method is used to print the number of remaining tickets after a successful and it works fine. I would like to know what's the best way to update the total tickets (ticket_quantity field in my table) with this value. I have seen some examples where they do it in controller. What's the Rails way?

I tried using ticket.ticket_quantity.save! and ticket.ticket_quantity.update etc. in the same model method but I encounter errors while doing it. Also, it would be great if you could point me to a resource that explores model methods in depth.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the models. You might want to define a delegation in your model. See http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate.

Comment: @CodeGnome I have updated the question with the ticket and booking models. Looking into delegates as well.

Comment: If I were modeling this, max tickets would be a property of event... and then I would use validations on Ticket to check to see if that was allowed... Bookings would then be created solely as a record of the transaction...

Comment: If you're going to use your current method simply put `ticket.save!` instead of `ticket.ticket_quantity.save!` and you should run fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are not saving the ticket so the update is discarded.

Have you tried

```
count = ticket.ticket_quantity.to_i - order_quantity.to_i
ticket.update_attribute(:ticket_quantity,count)
```

`update_attribute` does not require a save as it auto saves without validations.

Although you should probably validate that the `order_quantity` is <= `ticket_quantity`

such as

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
 ...
  #just threw this in for you too
  after_create :update_ticket_count

  validates :order_quantity, numericality:{less_than_or_equal_to: ->(booking){ booking.ticket.ticket_quantity}}

  def update_ticket_count
    ticket.update_attribute(:ticket_quantity,ticket.ticket_quantity.to_i - self.order_quantity)
  end

end
```